# Axis flipping in OpenLayers

Tags: leaflet, openlayers

I have a map working using Leaflet as follows, using EPSG 2236 and a custom tilegrid.  I want to switch to OpenLayers 3 so I can use the map rotation functionality but I am having trouble setting up the projection.

```
var bbox = [0, 5000000, 14747959, 19747959];
var maxResolution = ( bbox[2]-bbox[0] )/256;

var crs = L.CRS.proj4js('EPSG:2263'
                         , '+proj=lcc +lat_1=41.03333333333333 +lat_2=40.66666666666666 +lat_0=40.16666666666666 +lon_0=-74 ' 
                         + '+x_0=300000.0000000001 ' 
                         + '+y_0=0 ' 
                         + '+ellps=GRS80 ' 
                         + '+datum=NAD83 ' 
                         + '+to_meter=0.3048006096012192 ' 
                         + '+no_defs ',
                         new L.Transformation(1,-bbox[0], -1, bbox[3]));

   crs.scale = function(zoom) {
       return 1 / (maxResolution / Math.pow(2, zoom));
   };
```

In particular, how can I replicate the flipping of the axis achieved using this?:

```
new L.Transformation(1,-bbox[0], -1, bbox[3])
```